# IIS rewrite one variable different URLs + redirect classic asp

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, iis, asp-classic

I have an app in classic asp and want to rewrite URLs.

From: `go.asp?t=5&group=XXXXXX&sub=YYYYY` to: `cat/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYYY`

and from: `go.asp?t=15&number=XXXXXXXX` to lets say: `S/XXXXXXXX`

and so on, I will have more rules just with different T variable values.
How can I write rewrite rules and proper redirect based on specific T value?

Comment: if you're going to down-vote a question, at least have the common courtesy of explaining why

Comment: with that said, you may want to read about the basics of URL Rewriting - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module Once you do that, and if you run into specific issues, come back with what you've done and where you're stuck and we should be able to help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a viable question to me. In Classic ASP, for a get, the querystring values are available in Request.QueryString("varname"). So you could do

```
dim t, sResult, oRequest
set oRequest = Request.QueryString ' convenience assignment
t = oRequest("t")
t = cLng(t) ' force t from string into a number
select case t

    case 1
        dim sGroup, sSub ' sub is a keyword to VBScript
        sGroup=oRequest("group") 
        sSub=oRequest("sub")

        sResult = "cat/" & sGroup & "/" & sSub

    case 15
        dim sNumber
        sNumber=oRequest("number")
        sResult = "S/" & sNumber
end select

response.redirect sResult
```

The code is untested but should lead you in the right direction. You can extend the cases and the URL param harvesting as required by your use case.

If it was me and there were a large number of cases I would probably set up some kind of metadata to describe what to harvest per value of 't' then have one function to handle the job based on that.

There 'are' more sophisticated IIS-level URL redirection features but they introduce other dependencies. If all you need to do is modify the incoming URL then this is a cheap and cheerful way forward.